# ¿Porque no se ejecuta un Timer con hora 0:01?

Tags: java, timer

Estoy haciendo funcionar un programa con un Timer, todos los días a una hora específica, el caso es que si lo configuro para que se ejecute a las 0:01 el Timer no se ejecuta, pero por ejemplo si lo configuro para las 0:02 se ejecuta sin ningún tipo de problema, alguien me puede explicar porque pasa esto?

Dejo un  ejemplo de lo como tengo todo montado, la clase que uso yo es muy similar a la descrita pero no idéntica, podrá ayudar a entender un poco mejor el problema que planteo.

si necesitáis que aclare algo más hacérmelo saber.

Gracias.

```
package com.autentia.tutorial.ejb.scheduler;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * Implementación del servicio @local IAlarmScheduler.
 */
@Stateless
public class AlarmScheduler implements IAlarmScheduler {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AlarmScheduler.class);

    /** Injección del TimerService */
    @Resource TimerService timerService;

    /** Hora de ejecución: 23 horas */
    private static final int START_HOUR = 23;

    /** Minutos de ejecución: 0 minutos */
    private static final int START_MINUTES = 0;

    /** Segundos de ejecución: 00  */
    private static final int START_SECONDS = 0;

    /** Intervalo de la ejecución: 1440 = 24 horas */
    private static final int INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 1440;

    /**
     * Levanta el servicio 
     */
    public void startUpTimer() {

        log.info("startUpTimer - alarm scheduler service is active.");

        shutDownTimer();

        Calendar initialExpiration = Calendar.getInstance();
        initialExpiration.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, START_HOUR );
        initialExpiration.set(Calendar.MINUTE, START_MINUTES);
        initialExpiration.set(Calendar.SECOND, START_SECONDS);

        long intervalDuration = new Integer(INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES).longValue()*60*1000;

        log.info("startUpTimer - create new timer service at \""+initialExpiration.getTime()+"\", with \""+intervalDuration+"\" interval in milis.");
        timerService.createTimer(initialExpiration.getTime(),intervalDuration,null);

    }

    /**
     * Para el servicio 
     */
    public void shutDownTimer() {
        Collection<Timer> timers = timerService.getTimers();
        log.info("shutDownTimer - existing timers? " + timers);
        if (timers != null)
        {
            for (Iterator iterator = timers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Timer t = (Timer) iterator.next();
                t.cancel();
                log.info("shutDownTimer - timer \""+t+"\" canceled.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  método callback que se invocará al terminar el intervalo definido
     */
    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer)
    {
        log.info("executing - " + timer.getInfo());

        // TODO: implementar la lógica del proceso de alarmas.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @David , para que te podamos ayudar mejor. ¿Puedes compartir el codigo que tienes hecho?

Comment: Hola @VictorManuel gracias por contestar, por desgracia no puedo compartir código por contrato de confidencialidad, pero ya te digo que por algo que esté mal codificado no es, tiene que ver con la clase TimerService que es la que se está usando, tengo la duda de si la hora que le intento configurar (0:01) sea una hora que la clase TimerService no tome en cuenta para ejecutar, ya que configurando para cualquier día de la semana y cualquier hora funciona correctamente, la excepcion ocurre con las 0:01 mminutos. Gracias

Comment: TimerService es una interfaz, no una clase. Podrías crear un [mcve] con un código similar al que tienes para intentar reproducir el escenario y aislar el comportamiento

Comment: @PabloLozano si correcto una Interfaz, me equivoqué al escribir, te pongo un ejemplo prácticamente idéntico de como tengo montado yo mi clase.

Comment: La línea `long intervalDuration = new Integer(INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES).longValue()*60*1000;` se podría simplificar a `long intervalDuration = INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES*60*1000;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás usando el método createTimer mal:

```
timerService.createTimer(initialExpiration.getTime(),intervalDuration,null);
```

Es un método con sobrecarga, y estás usando la versión con las siguientes características:

> ```
> Timer createTimer(long initialDuration,
>               long intervalDuration,
>               java.io.Serializable info)
>               throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,
>                      java.lang.IllegalStateException,
>                      EJBException
> ```
>
> Create an interval timer whose first expiration occurs after a specified duration, and whose subsequent expirations occur after a specified interval.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - initialDuration - The number of milliseconds that must elapse before the first timer expiration notification.
> - intervalDuration - The number of milliseconds that must elapse between timer expiration notifications. Expiration notifications are scheduled relative to the
>     time of the first expiration. If expiration is delayed (e.g. due to
>     the interleaving of other method calls on the bean), two or more
>     expiration notifications may occur in close succession to "catch up".
> - info - application information to be delivered along with the timer
>     expiration. This can be null.
>
> Returns: the newly created Timer.

Es decir, el primer parámetro es el número de milisegundos que deben pasar hasta la primera ejecución. No es el `UNIX Time`, no es una fecha. Si estás usando la fecha actual para generar el número, estás indicando que deben pasar los mismos milisegundos que los que han pasado desde el 1 de enero de 1970 hasta ahora (más de 49 años).

Podrías probar con [este otro método](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createIntervalTimer(java.util.Date,%20long,%20javax.ejb.TimerConfig)), donde el primer parámetro si debe ser una fecha. El tercer parámetro parece ser también opcional, con lo que el funcionamiento debería ser similar a lo que pretendes:

```
Timer createIntervalTimer(java.util.Date initialExpiration,
                      long intervalDuration,
                      TimerConfig timerConfig)
                      throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,
                             java.lang.IllegalStateException,
                             EJBException
```